# toprule and bottomrule next to align within table - errors & spacing problems

Tags: tables, errors, align

The following table gives 2 errors:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}     
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Ableitungen der dimensionslosen freien Enthalpie $\gamma$, Gl. \ref{glg_IF97_R1_Basis}}
    \label{tab:IF97_R1_Abl}
    \toprule
        \begin{align}
            \gamma_\pi          &= \left( \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \pi} \right)_{\tau}       & &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{34} -n_i I_i (7,1-\pi)^{I_i-1} (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i}   \\
            \gamma_{\pi\pi} &= \left( \frac{\partial^2 \gamma}{\partial \pi^2} \right)_{\tau} &  &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{34} n_i I_i (I_i -1)(7,1-\pi)^{I_i-2} (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i}   \\            
            \gamma_\tau     &= \left( \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \tau} \right)_{\pi}       & &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{34} n_i(7,1-\pi)^{I_i} J_i (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i-1}   \\
            \gamma_{\tau\tau}   &= \left( \frac{\partial^2 \gamma}{\partial \tau^2} \right)_{\pi} & &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{34} n_i(7,1-\pi)^{I_i} J_i (J_i -1) (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i-2} \\
            \gamma_{\pi \tau} &= \left( \frac{\partial^2 \gamma}{\partial \pi \partial \tau} \right) & &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{34} -n_i I_i (7,1-\pi)^{I_i-1} J_i (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i-1} 
        \end{align} 
        \bottomrule
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Those errors relate to `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`, though I'm not sure why:

> Misplaced \noalign
>
> \bottomrule ->\noalign

I also can't figure out how to decrease the enormous space between left and right side of the equations, an why there is so much space after and before the lines on top and bottom. Maybe it's related to the error?

Comment: I wouldn't use `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` in this context. Simply use `\hrule`.

Comment: @Mico: `\hrule`  or `\hline`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Definitely `\hrule`. The issue is that the horizontal lines aren't embedded in a `tabular`-like structure. Hence, LaTeX doesn't know how wide `\hline`, `\toprule`, or `\bottomrule` need to be made. The TeX macro `\hrule` simply draws a line across the entire width of the text block. I think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @Mico: I know know -- I missed the missing `tabular` environment in the MWE. Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}     
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Ableitungen der dimensionslosen freien Enthalpie $\gamma$, Gl. \ref{glg_IF97_R1_Basis}}
\label{tab:IF97_R1_Abl}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
\toprule
\addlinespace[-\normalbaselineskip]
{\begin{alignat}{2}
 \gamma_\pi        &= \left( \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \pi} \right)_{\tau}          &&= \sum_{i=1}^{34} -n_i I_i (7,1-\pi)^{I_i-1} (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i}   \\
 \gamma_{\pi\pi}   &= \left( \frac{\partial^2 \gamma}{\partial \pi^2} \right)_{\tau}      &&= \sum_{i=1}^{34} n_i I_i (I_i -1)(7,1-\pi)^{I_i-2} (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i}   \\            
 \gamma_\tau       &= \left( \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \tau} \right)_{\pi}          &&= \sum_{i=1}^{34} n_i(7,1-\pi)^{I_i} J_i (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i-1}   \\
 \gamma_{\tau\tau} &= \left( \frac{\partial^2 \gamma}{\partial \tau^2} \right)_{\pi}      &&= \sum_{i=1}^{34} n_i(7,1-\pi)^{I_i} J_i (J_i -1) (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i-2} \\
 \gamma_{\pi \tau} &= \left( \frac{\partial^2 \gamma}{\partial \pi \partial \tau} \right) &&= \sum_{i=1}^{34} -n_i I_i (7,1-\pi)^{I_i-1} J_i (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i-1} 
 \end{alignat}}
\\
\addlinespace[-\normalbaselineskip]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That also solves the spacing problem. Great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to embed the `align` environment in a `tabular`-like environment, and if you simply want to draw lines across the full width of the text block, don't use `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`. Just use `\hrule` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}     
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    %\centering
    \caption{Ableitungen der dimensionslosen freien Enthalpie $\gamma$, Gl. \ref{glg_IF97_R1_Basis}}
    \label{tab:IF97_R1_Abl}

    \hrule
        \begin{align}
            \gamma_\pi          &= \left( \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \pi} \right)_{\tau}       & &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{34} -n_i I_i (7,1-\pi)^{I_i-1} (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i}   \\
            \gamma_{\pi\pi} &= \left( \frac{\partial^2 \gamma}{\partial \pi^2} \right)_{\tau} &  &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{34} n_i I_i (I_i -1)(7,1-\pi)^{I_i-2} (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i}   \\            
            \gamma_\tau     &= \left( \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \tau} \right)_{\pi}       & &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{34} n_i(7,1-\pi)^{I_i} J_i (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i-1}   \\
            \gamma_{\tau\tau}   &= \left( \frac{\partial^2 \gamma}{\partial \tau^2} \right)_{\pi} & &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{34} n_i(7,1-\pi)^{I_i} J_i (J_i -1) (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i-2} \\
            \gamma_{\pi \tau} &= \left( \frac{\partial^2 \gamma}{\partial \pi \partial \tau} \right) & &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{34} -n_i I_i (7,1-\pi)^{I_i-1} J_i (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i-1} 
        \end{align} 

\hrule
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a tabular or tabularx environment, if you want to use `\toprule` and the like:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{-2ex}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{-0.5ex}
    \caption{Ableitungen der dimensionslosen freien Enthalpie $\gamma$, Gl. \ref{glg_IF97_R1_Basis}}
    \label{tab:IF97_R1_Abl}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}%{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}
  \toprule
        {\begin{align}
            \gamma_\pi &= \left( \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \pi} \right)_{\tau} & &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{34} -n_i I_i (7,1-\pi)^{I_i-1} (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i} \\
               \gamma_{\pi\pi} &= \left( \frac{\partial^2 \gamma}{\partial \pi^2} \right)_{\tau} & &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{34} n_i I_i (I_i -1)(7,1-\pi)^{I_i-2} (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i} \\
             \gamma_\tau &= \left( \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \tau} \right)_{\pi} & &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{34} n_i(7,1-\pi)^{I_i} J_i (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i-1} \\
             \gamma_{\tau\tau} &= \left( \frac{\partial^2 \gamma}{\partial \tau^2} \right)_{\pi} & &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{34} n_i(7,1-\pi)^{I_i} J_i (J_i -1) (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i-2} \\
             \gamma_{\pi \tau} &= \left( \frac{\partial^2 \gamma}{\partial \pi \partial \tau} \right) & &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{34} -n_i I_i (7,1-\pi)^{I_i-1} J_i (\tau - 1,222)^{J_i-1}
        \end{align}}\\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the `\centering` instruction still needed?

Comment: @Mico: You're right. Initially I tested a `0.9\linewidth`, which required it. Loading `listliketab` isn't needed either for this code, nor `floatflt`.

Comment: This is true. Sorry!

Comment: Don't feel sorry! I was only joking… Sometimes I wonder if I'm needed myself.